# SSL pinning android requiring illogical permissions

Tags: android, ssl

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_STATE" />
```

in order for ssl pinning to work, i have to require at least one of those permissions in my manifest.Why such a crazy thing?

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Reported on android 6.0

targetsdkversion i used is 22.

If i use targetsdkversion 23, i have to request permission for one of those..restart my app in order https call to work lol.

```
public static SSLContext getSSL() {
    try {           
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        AssetManager assetManager = BankNizwaApp.getAppContext()
                .getAssets();
        InputStream caInput = assetManager.open("cert.pem");
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate ca = null;
        try {
            ca = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) cf
                    .generateCertificate(caInput);
        } catch (Exception er) {
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca",
                (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) ca);
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And what I get

```
 <html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 12896453146718244255</body></html>
```

Comment: Post your code, along with the stack traces that occur when you lack those permissions. Note that there is no `android.permission.PHONE_STATE` permission in Android.

Comment: added what i get from server side as well, if i dont require READ_PHONE_STATE or PHONE_CALL.